# ¿Cómo hacer esta fórmula condicional en excel?

Tags: excel

Quisiera crear una condición que si la persona subió de peso el valor vaya a la celda de kg bajados y si aumentó vaya a la celda de Kg subidos.
Como referencia el peso inicial es ascendente en el ej el primer valor es el peso de 84 kg y el siguiente 80kg.

[image: Imagen de excel]

Comment: cual valor es al que te refieres?, como determinas que alguien subió o bajó de peso? como tienes la fórmula armada al menos en borrador?

Comment: indica las fechas si van ascendente o descendente debido a que no se sabe si subió de 80,00 -> 84,00 o bajó de 84,00 -> 80,00

Comment: Es ascendente el primer valor es el peso de 84kg en el primer control de peso.

Comment: insisto cual es la lógica para determinar si suben o bajan de peso?

Comment: La lógica es =si(A2>A3) El resultado de la resta va en kg bajados pero si (A2<A3)entonces el resultado va en kg subidos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función SI=(Condición;"lo que muestra si se cumple la condición";"Lo que muestra si no se cumple")

Funcion B3

[image: Resultado B3]

Funcion C3

[image: Resultado C3]

Answer (score 3):

Adicional al condicional `SI` que posee excel, también permite convertir el `FALSO` y el `VERDADERO` en `0` y en `1` respectivamente, lo cual es muy útil si empleas matrices -ninguna de las celdas puede estar vacía y/o contener valores diferentes a números-

Aquí como opera este concepto

```
=(2>1)       ## Se imprime VERDADERO
=(2<1)       ## Se imprime FALSO

=--(2>1)     ## Se imprime 1
=--(2<1)     ## Se imprime 0
```

La expresión `--` convierte la salida de una expresión lógica en número.

Por tanto la fórmula en B3 es:

```
=--(A2>A3)*(A2-A3)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la formula en C3 es:

```
=--(A2<A3)*(A3-A2)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]