# Seleccionar una celda en función del valor devuelto en la celda anterior

Tags: excel, sql, indices

Estoy realizando un informe de estadísticas de consultas de **SQL** en **excel** y en una celda tengo puesto cual es la consulta que más tiempo tardó en ejecutarse (con una función `MAX` del propio **excel**).

Me gustaría poner en el campo de al lado el `ID` de la query en cuestión (que la tengo contemplada en una celda).

Es decir: si la query que más tardó es la que está en `D5`, quiero coger el campo `A5`, que es quien almacena el `ID`.

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo bien se tiene un `rango` *(arreglo)* con tiempos y se necesita la `celda` *(indice)* que contiene el mayor de ellos, considerando además que el `máximo valor` pueda estar repetido en dicho `rango` *(arreglo)*.

Se puede conseguir lo anterior, pero dado que requiere varios pasos y funciones voy a colocar primero el resultado final.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para ello, sugiero que se trabaje en una hoja (`queryMax`) aparte esta consulta, porque de lo contrario, se podría incurrir en errores involuntarios con los indices y la posición relativa de las celdas.

En la columna `A` se aprecia que los tiempos máximos son `A5`, `A6`, `A7` y `A9` para efectos de la solución se toma el primero de ellos es decir `A5`

Luego para la fila `2` desde la columna `B` hasta la columna `G` iría lo siguiente:

Celda **B2**

```
=JERARQUIA(A2;A:A)
```

Se efectua un ranking para el valor `A2` en relación a toda la columna `A` que es `A:A`.

Celda **C2**

```
=--(B2=1)*CELDA("fila";$A2)
```

Se devuelve el número de fila si el ranking es **1**, caso contrario se imprime cero **0**.

> Para más detalle de la celda `C2` ver [¿Cómo hacer esta fórmula condicional en excel?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/235940/c%C3%B3mo-hacer-esta-f%C3%B3rmula-condicional-en-excel).

Celda **D2**

```
=SI(C2<>0;SI(SUMA($D$1:D1)>0;0;1);0)
```

Aquí los condicionales anidados trabajan primero para verificar que `fil_Indice` no sea cero `0` para ir sumando el rango de celdas previas en `fil_Indice_Ajus` siempre y cuando dicha suma no haya excedido la unidad `1` caso contrario se colocará cero `0`.

Celda **E2**

```
=DIRECCION(SUMAPRODUCTO(C:C;D:D);1;4)
```

El arreglo binario que se ha obtenido en la columna `D` permite cuando se multiplica y suma por la columna `C` obtener el número `5`, dicho número es la fila, `1` es la columna `A` y cuatro `(4)` es una referencia del **tipo relativa** de la [Función DIRECCIÓN](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/direccion-funci%C3%B3n-direccion-d0c26c0d-3991-446b-8de4-ab46431d4f89).

Celda **F2**

```
=INDIRECTO(E2)
```

Devuelve el valor contenido en una celda, en función al nombre de la celda contenida en `E2`.

Celda **G2**

```
=(MAX(A:A)=F2)
```

Por último se verifica si la función `MAX` calza con el valor máximo visto con las Funciones Previas.

La respuesta ha sido bastante extensa por las funciones expuestas.

> **Consideración:** si al costado de los tiempos se maneja un `ID` propio, empleando las funciones de la celda **E2** y **F2** se puede capturar dicho `ID` también, en función a la columna que los contenga.

Asimismo, aunque no ha sido parte de la pregunta, creo que esto se podría lograr también a través de **sql**, por ejemplo creando una tabla y guardando los registros por fecha o tipo de consulta para luego usar MAX con `TOP 1` o `LIMIT 1` y guardar en una variable el `indice` para vincularlo luego con **excel**.

Considero que la respuesta que proporcioné en [procedimientos almacenados mysql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/242231/procedimientos-almacenados-mysql/242323#242323) se podría adaptar a vuestras necesidades, a no ser claro, que se esté buscando algo diferente.

Comment: Muchas gracias Hubert por la respuesta tan detallada. Finalmente, he sacado el valor que necesito utilizando la función IFS de excel.

No es la solución más elegante, puesto que he tenido que concatenar los 30 supuestos, pero al menos ha dado solución a mi problema.

Comment: Qué bueno, te felicito porque la pregunta no era sencilla, sólo quería acotar que si al costado de los tiempos se maneja un `ID` propio, empleando las funciones de la celda **E2** y **F2** se puede capturar dicho `ID` también.