# Ayuda con "openpyxl"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy trabajando con una hoja de *Excel* de la cual necesito sacar un valor máximo que está en el rango de **B5-B93** y un dato que lo acompaña en la columna anterior, en el rango **A5-A93**.

Esto es lo que llevo hasta el momento:

```
import openpyxl

doc = openpyxl.load_workbook('CENIZA_1.xlsx')
AcelSis = doc['Exported Data']['B5':'B93']


AcMax = 0
for row in AcelSis:
    for cell in row:

        if AcMax < cell.value:
            AcMax = cell.value
            PerAcMax = cell    # Aquí obtengo la tupla que representa la ubicación en la hoja de excel de AcMax

conjunto = [PerAcMax, AcMax]

print(conjunto)
```

Obtengo esto:

```
[<Cell 'Exported Data'.B61>, 2.3910281658172607]
```

Hasta el momento obtengo sin problemas el máximo, pero no sé como obtener el valor que lo acompaña (PerAcMax). Agradezco la ayuda, esto es parte esencial de mi trabajo de grados ya que tengo que obtener estos valor de 300 archivos *Excel* mas.

O si hay un procedimiento más eficiente lo agradecería enormemente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como en la pregunta no se precisa qué hacer si hay máximos repetidos voy asumir que se toma la posición del primero de ellos, esto incluso fue tratado en esta pregunta [Seleccionar una celda en función del valor devuelto en la celda anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245276/seleccionar-una-celda-en-funci%C3%B3n-del-valor-devuelto-en-la-celda-anterior).

Sugiero que se trabaje con una lista, los valores de la `columna B` y luego mediante el método `.index()` hallar la posición respectiva del valor encontrado.

En tal sentido, el código con sus respectivos comentarios quedaría así:

```
import openpyxl

libro = "CENIZA_1.xlsx"
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(libro)

# se verifica que hojas tiene el libro
print(workbook.sheetnames)
# ['Exported Data']

# Se seleciona la hoja con la que se va ha trabajar
exported_data = workbook['Exported Data']

# Rango filas de las columna A y B
empieza_fila = 5
termina_fila = 93

# Se coge los elementos de la columna B
listB = [exported_data['B' + str(i)].value for i in range(empieza_fila , termina_fila + 1)]
# print(listB)

print("\n", max(listB))
# 1242

print(listB.index(max(listB)))
# 55
# este número corresponde a la
# posición de la listB para su máximo valor


# Se suma la variable empieza_fila
indice = listB.index(max(listB)) + empieza_fila

celda_A_max = 'A' + str(indice)
celda_B_max = 'B' + str(indice)

maxA = exported_data[celda_A_max].value
maxB = exported_data[celda_B_max].value

#Valores
print(maxA, maxB)
# auto58 1242

# Celdas
print(celda_A_max, celda_B_max)
# A60 B60
```

Comprobado con el **Excel**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se mencionó al inicio de la respuesta, el código de arriba, tomará el primer máximo que se encuentre, si se necesitase saber que celdas son máximas, *-en este caso las filas 60 y 80-* se podría emplear `enumerate` y crear `tuplas` en  una lista.

```
print([(k,v) for k,v in enumerate(listB) if v==maxB])
# [(55, 1242), (83, 1242)]
# 55 + 5 = 60
# 83 + 5 = 88
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias, justo se me había ocurrido, algo similar para obtener estos valores cuando vi tu respuesta. ¿Sabes cómo puedo hacer este mismo proceso, para los otros 299 archivos de Excel que tengo?

Comment: Hola @RichardA.RamosTrujillo si los archivos están en la misma carpeta, se puede conseguir los nombres de los mismos y almacenarlos en una lista para después abrirlos con `openpyxl`, hice un pequeño *snippet* sobre eso el año pasado, puedes verlo acá [getFilesNames](https://hubertronald.github.io/Get%20Files%20Name.html)

Comment: Gracias, lo revisaré mañana y te contaré por acá qué tal me va.

Comment: ¡Funcionó!, con un pequeño inconveniente en realidad, me lee los archivos en este orden: **CENIZA_1.xlsx, CENIZA_10.xlsx, CENIZA_100.xlsx, CENIZA_101.xlsx, CENIZA_102.xlsx, ..., CENIZA_199.xlsx, CENIZA_2.xlsx, CENIZA_20.xlsx, CENIZA_200.xlsx, ...**

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: Hola @RichardA.RamosTrujillo, por la estructura que tienen los nombres, lo más práctico es hacer una lista comprimida `["CENIZA_"+str(n)+".xlsx" for n in range(1,201)]`... Por otro lado, ordenar la lista que se expone, también es factible, pero como eso escapa a la pregunta inicial, te sugiero que lo plasmes como una nueva pregunta, así obtendrás muchos enfoques para la solución y sobre todo, quedará un registro de la pregunta y su solución para futuras referencias.

Answer (score 1):

Así quedó el programa:

```
import openpyxl

doc = openpyxl.load_workbook('CENIZA_1.xlsx')
# Selecciona la hoja que se trabajará
sheet = doc['Exported Data']

# Se crean las listas a las que se le añadirán los valores de Excel
Aceleraciones = []
Periodos = []

# Ciclo que recorre las filas
for Per, Ace in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=5, max_row=93, min_col=1, max_col=2):

    Periodos.append(Per.value)
    Aceleraciones.append(Ace.value)

AceMax = max(Aceleraciones)
Indice = Aceleraciones.index(AceMax)
PerMax = Periodos[Indice]

Conjunto = [PerMax, AceMax]

print(Conjunto)
```

El cuál me da como salida, los valores que buscaba.

```
[0.44999998807907104, 2.3910281658172607]
```